# Can we return Two Arrays in one tableview numberOfRowsInSection without using section in swift?

Tags: json, swift, uitableview, uicollectionviewcell

I am displaying all contacts in tableview.. but here

two service calls for two conditions 1) tagged 2) filter

now i need to check these 2 conditions in my total contacts and display accordingly

i have designed cell for all contacts tableview like below:

[image]

here: **if the contact is tagged then i need to show tagged in place of invite button**

**if contact is filtered then i need to show onFilter in place of invite button** and remaining should be invite... how to do that all in one cell? please suggest me

Initially i have tried tableview with two prototype cells and displaying like below and working:

```
  var jsonArrayFilter = [ContactJsonFilter]()
 var jsonArrayTagged = [ContactDetailsJsonTagged]()

  func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return 2
 }

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    
    if section == 0{
        return jsonArrayTagged.count
    }
    else{
        return jsonArrayFilter.count
    }
}
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    

if indexPath.section == 0{
    var cell: ContactsTableViewCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "ContactsTableViewCell", for: indexPath) as! ContactsTableViewCell
                         
        let taggedContactJson = jsonArrayTagged[indexPath.row]
             
                cell.nameLbl.text = taggedContactJson.Name
                cell.empRoleLbl.text = taggedContactJson.phnum
      
                
                let conTaggedStat: Bool = taggedContactJson.isTaggedReq!
                
                if conTaggedStat == true{
                   
                    cell.taggedBtn.setTitle("Tagged", for: .normal)
                }
        
        return cell
                
    }
    
    
    if indexPath.section == 1{
        
        var cell1: ContactsTableViewCell2 = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "ContactsTableViewCell2", for: indexPath) as! ContactsTableViewCell2
                                  
                let aJson = jsonArrayFilter[indexPath.row]

        cell1.filterBtn.setTitle("Filter", for: .normal)

                cell1.nameLbl.text = aJson.userName
                cell1.empRoleLbl.text = aJson.phnum

        return cell1
        
    }

    return UITableViewCell()
}
```

**but i need to check two conditions in one cell not in two seperate cells. how is that possible?**

**EDIT**:  My two APIs struct... how to make them in single array

```
struct ContactJsonFilter {

var userId: String?
var userType: String?
var onItag: Bool?
var taggedStat: Bool?
var userName: String?
var phnum: String?

init(userId: String, oniTaag: Bool, tagged: Bool, userName: String, key: String) {

    self.userId = userId
    self.userType = userType
    self.onItag = oniTaag
    self.taggedStat = tagged
    self.userName = userName
    self.phnum = key
}
}
struct ContactDetailsJsonTagged {

var userId: String?
var userType: String?
var fName: String?
var lName: String?
var phnum: String?
var isTaggedReq: Bool?
var status: String?

init(userId: String, userType: String, firstName: String, lastName: String, phone: String, isTaggedWithRequestor: Bool, status: String) {

    self.userId = userId
    self.userType = userType
    self.fName = firstName
    self.lName = lastName
    self.phnum = phone
    self.isTaggedReq = isTaggedWithRequestor
    self.status = status
    
}
}
```

Comment: you can call 10 API's sir .... no issue on number :)

Comment: @jawadAli in `numberOfRowsInSection` how can we call sir

Comment: how you are calling first API?

Comment: @jawadAli `if section == 0{  return jsonArrayTagged.count` and `if section == 1{  return jsonArrayFilter.countt` like this.. here i am facing issue

Comment: You should not call network APIs in cells at all. Cells are volatile and can be deallocated immediately.

Comment: @vadian is correct ... you usually call API in didLoad or appear

Comment: You can check for everything if you create an adequate data model and the conditions are distinct.